# Remove last item and preceding undefined entries from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good day,

I am trying to remove the last item from an array in JavaScript, and all the `undefined` values preceding it up till the point where an item in the array is not `undefined` again.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7]
 for (;;) {
   var lastItem = arr.pop();
   if (lastItem !== undefined && arr.length >= 0) {
     doStuff(lastItem);
     break;
   }
 }
```

the expected elements in the array using the snip above will be:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6]` - which is perfect. However:

I want to get rid of the infinite loop, and also avoid recursion, `while(true)` or anything of that sort. I am getting stuck here however, how can I find the trailing undefined entries after I have used `arr.pop()`, and remove them? I cannot use `arr.compact()` - as I rely on the `undefined` entry after `5` to stay in tact: I do not want to remove 'falsey' values.

Comment: check below my answer I think This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7]

 const lastItem = arr.pop();
 for (let i = arr.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
   if(arr[i]===undefined) arr.pop();
   else break;
 }
 
 console.log(arr)
```

Comment: He also wants to save the last item, so `const lastItem = arr.pop()`

Comment: Your solution might actually work with some modification - I still wish to remove the last item :)

Comment: @Eon You should then state more clearly what you want. I think it prints what you stated in question..

Comment: @giogim I will certainly try next time :) english isn't my mother tongue. however, your solution is perfect and will be marked as the answer

Comment: I upvoted and marked answer. thank you, this is a simple solution which my fellow developers will understand and it would put their mind to rest that I haven't soiled our system with infinite loops :3

Comment: @Eon Fine just this code will delete last item also in the case if *last item itself is undefined*. If you don't want that, you can change code.

Comment: @giogim I had noticed that, and implemented around it :)

Answer (score 0):

just loop while your last element is undefined :

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7]

let lastItem = arr.pop();
while(arr[arr.length - 1] == undefined && arr.length){
    arr.pop();
    lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.pop` while `lastItem = undefined`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7];
arr.pop();
while(arr[arr.length-1] == undefined && arr.length>0) arr.pop();
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7];

var result = arr.slice(0, (arr.indexOf(undefined) == -1 ? arr.length : arr.indexOf(undefined) + 2));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the last element by changing the `length` of the array and check if the last element is `undefined`. Then proceed until no more `undefined` values are at the end.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7];

do ; while (--array.length && array[array.length - 1] === undefined)

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyy.. Its preety simple. 
Above example solved for you.

```
 Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 6, undefined, undefined, 7]

arr.clean(undefined)
arr.pop()
```

*Explanation*

1. First create a prototype function to remove a supplied element.
2. use the created clean function for array. Use clean function to remove [undefined] value from [arr] array.
3. Pop out the last element using pop() function .

Simple as that . Hope this helps

Comment: This removes ALL undefined, and that's not what the OP wants.